# .htaccess rewrite file to file without ext and folder to one file

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite

Here's what I talking about:

```
localhost/add.php -> localhost/add
localhost/1234/ -> localhost/view.php?id=1234
```

What I have tried:

```
RewriteRule (.*)$ /view.php?id=$1
RewriteRule (.*) $1.php [L]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this what you're looking for?

```
Options -MultiViews
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/]+) view.php?id=$1&%{QUERY_STRING} [L]
```